# How to do administrative task scheduler in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I am trying to convert DB2 queries for PostgreSQL database. I have following DB2 queries . I just want to convert these queries to PostgreSQL.

```
db2set DB2_ATS_ENABLE=YES#
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD('poll EVERY 2 MINUTE',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL,NULL,'0-59/2 * * * *','db2admin','GET_STATUS_INSERT',NULL, NULL,NULL)#
```

This is the administrative task scheduler in DB2. I want to convert to PostgreSQL for doing same task. Is it any similar queries in PostgreSQL?

Comment: No, Postgres has no built-in scheduler. Just schedule those scripts as a regular cron job. Or you might want to install [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)

Comment: Is it something like `SELECT cron.schedule('0 11 * * *', 'MSG');` instead of `CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD` ?